# float:left not working after specifying width

Tags: html, css

```
.container {
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}

.container .unit {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="unit">
        <img src="img.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="unit">
        <img src="img2.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work, why?/how should I do it??/what is the right way?
Edited to add another div.

Comment: if it is floating, text-align won't do anything here ... but what is it that is not working btw ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bh1ytnmf/2/   its working here.. what is the meaning of not working?

Comment: why position:relative when floating?

Comment: I see @whatever fiddle working with `float:left` with the `width` property set

Comment: @GCyrillus, I have multiple "unit" divs (I edited the code to show this), the divs don't float next to teach other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the width of your pictures, this is my best "guess" of what your issue is. see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ujg77o3r/3/

The top 2 images have width's that are equal to (or can be less then) the width of the `container` once the 2 images combined are bigger then the 100px the image will go bellow, you can see the second example in the fiddle.

If this is your issue, set the widths of the combined image widths to less then the width of the container.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="unit">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .unit {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I feel really dumb, this was the problem. the width property is supposed to be for the .unit class, not its container

Comment: Oh, I was wondering why you had 100px for a container. Makes sense now :)

Comment: @w4j3d it happens when you exhaust yourself too much.. Happens to me too... :/